# Why my filtering and sorting is not working?

Tags: javascript, sorting, reactjs, filter, react-native

I have an array of object `event` where each event has a start date and an end date.

I am trying to filter the events by removing any events that are older than `now`. Then, I am trying to sort my events as most recent to then display them on the screen.

I am using the following routine:

```
constructor(props) {

    // ..
    this.props.events = this.filterAndSortEvents(props.events);
}

filterAndSortEvents(events: Object)
{
    let Original = events;
    const now = new Date();

    // filter
    let Filtered = events.map(function(e) {
        if(e.endDate > Date.now())
        { return e }
    });

    // sort
    let Sorted = Filtered.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.startDate > b.startDate ? -1 : a.startDate < b.startDate ? 1 : 0;
    });

    return Sorted;
}
```

But it is not working:

Comment: Try setting the events property to the class, using `this.events` vs `this.props.events`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you consider to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering.

```
let filtered = events.filter(e => e.endDate > Date.now());
```

You could use the delta of the time as sort return value ([`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works in situ.)

```
filtered.sort((a, b) => b.startDate - a.startDate);
```

and return `filtered`

```
return filtered;
```

<sup>Just a small hint, usually instancable function are usually written with upper case first letter.</sup>

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see any change.. Any advice?

Comment: please supply a small amout of data for filtering.

Comment: Turned out that `this.props.events` is static and its value can not be changed. Hence why I could not see the new changes.

Answer (score 3):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you need this:

```
// filter
let Filtered = events.filter(x=> e.endDate > Date.now());
```

About sorting, at first, conditional-operator may work not as expected in your case:

```
 // sort
    let Sorted = Filtered.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.startDate > b.startDate 
           ? -1 
           : (a.startDate < b.startDate ? 1 : 0);
    });
```

Second, you can try to use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or [Array.prototype.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) for sorting